# How to send sparse vectors and matrices over ZeroMQ?

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, zeromq, chapel

I have a matrix `A` (how many stories start this way?) that is sparse.

```
[
[0,   0, 0, 1.2, 0]
[0,   0, 0, 0,   0]
[3.5, 0, 0, 0,   0]
[0    7, 0, 0,   0]
]
```

I want to send variants of this back and forth between processes using ZeroMQ.  Assume the client and servers are of different languages that have no common serialization format.  Here are some tasks.

1. Create `A`.  This is complicated by needing to send the "frame" of the matrix, here `(4,5)`.
2. Update `A[4,2]` from 7 to 6.
3. Take a sparse vector `v=[0,0,3.1,0,0]` and multiply it by `A` and get the result back.

I've been told that sending byte streams is probably the best solution, but I can't find any examples between different libraries and in a sparse format.

My default will be to have a Python, C++ or Chapel pairing if someone can speak to those.

Comment: if you are sending and receiving in python you can probably use pickle to serialize it. If not, probably something like a JSON representation that can be created and parsed by different libraries would be an option.

Comment: I was told the JSON would be inefficient, but I'm new to this.  That is my fallback position.  Also, I can't count on the "other" side being Python.

Comment: Could be, hard to say without testing it though. Depends on the size of the matrix etc. There are HashMap / Dictionary representations of Sparse Matrices that should be easyish to parse / serialize in different languages.

Comment: You don't happen to have an example on you, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the design is very simple, I decided to go with a string representation with preset delimiters. Without something like protobuf it was easy to just have an understood protocol.  I used the format:

```
msg = '<i_index>:<j_index>:<value>^<i_index>:<j_index>:<value>`
```

In my case, the server already knew the frame of the matrix. So to send the vector `[0 0 0.8 0 0 1.4 0 0]` I would do

```
msg = '0:2:0.8^0:5:1.4'
```

It works so long as I don't have to send the massive matrix over.

Answer (score 1):

### As [you already know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172614/use-chapel-to-handle-massive-matrix), Brian, ZeroMQ is not the problem here

lets try to re-wrap the problem formulation first:

1. [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) will get all the features a `use ZMQ;` will provide
2. from ZeroMQ point of view, not the originator's side [python](/questions/tagged/python), but the [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) ( or C++, as you've mentioned above ) target environment will decide on a best choice of The best serialisation strategy provider, as the de-ser will obviously have to work inside the particular target language implementation ( yes, ZeroMQ will do its best to carry all the necessary payloads, byte-by-byte, so nothing dangerous here, even with the current state of the `ZMQ`-module issue, being recently under  review ), but the de-ser decides, once the data have come in ( as have been put in many of my ZeroMQ answers, ZMQ will either deliver a complete original message or none at all -- this immediately ceases as a dangerous No-Go-strategy to try to move the whole massive-Matrix at once ... ).
3. the extreme care taken on sparse-matrix tools also means, there is rather a need to "communicate" the sparse-matrix (re-)-representation, than to "send"-it ( if not just due to not available `[SPACE]` on the originator's node, then due to most probably very different representations of the sparse-matrix content )

### A concept of the possible solution:

This said, my choice would be to create an intelligent distributed agent-based system translation, that will allow target-environment to ask the originator's side ( where the massive sparse-matrix was assembled ) to start the process of re-representation of the massive sparse-matrix onto the target-environment, where such "replication-via-smart-communicated-content" will become ready for [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) in `{ Matrix | sparseMatrix }` type of such content re-representation, that is ready for `use LinearAlgebra;`

Simply forget to hunt for any low-hanging fruits offered so far, the `[SPACE]` will kill any JSON-grown-in-size-re-wrapped-original-Massive-matrix, that **1st** will hardly fit on the same Node in-RAM footprint and **2nd** will next crash even the Zero-Copy ( as there will the copies of such data-Peta-BLOB attempted to be placed into O/S & kernel network buffers etc )  and **that will not fly**.

Comment: Would it make sense to use the message topic like `multiply this by A` and then send a bytestream of `(int,int,float)` triples for the server to unpack? I guess you'd need the first two ints to be the frame of the vector.  But then you need a message type for every operation.

Comment: And, no, ZeroMQ is certainly not the problem here, I'm just learning how to use it efficiently.

Comment: ATM, when Chapel ZMQ module is under a general review / repair ( due to reasons outside the scope of this note ) my experience would drive me towards a intelligent dFSA-design. If dFSA-states/rules analysis is complete ( with a reasonably supported belief, there are no surprises expected to appear round the corner ( like "... hey, and we need also this and sometimes that ... :o)   ... One can work with several ( if not many ) specialised channels - one: int-hashed-dFSA-CMD, using ( working ) PUSH-PULL, next int-transport-DATA1, int-transport-DATA2, real-transport-DATA3, int-checksum-CRC, etc.